# How to make all alignment button of each column in same row?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm stuck in a css position, how can I make all alignment button of each column in same row? I'm using wordpress plugin and tried used css to select class name, but class name are specify for all button, please somebody help me out..[image: Here is my web screenshot]

Comment: Please include your code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Hi, I'm using wordpress plugin to develop this

Comment: apply height for the text above the button

Comment: You will need to provide some sort of code for us to work with. It may be a wordpress plugin but there will be code underlying its styling. Possibly a link to the page might help.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's hard to help without actual code but you could try setting the column CSS to `position: relative` with a defined height and change the button CSS to `position: absolute;` with `bottom: 20px`; this will force the button to the bottom of the container so they all appear inline.

Comment: http://amore2.voodooblowfish.com/
This is the link to source page, the problem is on home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

CSS

```
.vc_gitem_row .vc_gitem-col {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 300px;
}


.vc_btn3-container.vc_btn3-left {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Note: You should scope this changes so they don't affect other sections of the site

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code this is a bit difficult to answer, but I would take a look at setting *min-height* for the description above the buttons. Then it would at least push all the buttons to be aligned in a row. You would have to go even further setting some media queries to improve this styling when it comes to mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to set height of Text container

```
max-height: 100px; //as your requirement
```

or set button wrapper style property

```
bottom:0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `min-height` value for product text content just above the button in product card.